# Angular: drop-downs are not working for the ng-selected option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The selected item is not showing in the drop-down

Html

```
<select  ng-model="selectedItemvalue">
    <option value="">--Select --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="sel in selectables" ng-selected="selectedItemvalue == sel" value="{{sel}}">{{sel}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
$scope.selectables = ["A","B","C"]
$scope.selectedItemvalue = ["C"];
```

Sample Code Link 1 : https://plnkr.co/edit/talQLhVXuVZRUlMQXUmW?p=preview . - with Angular 1.0.7

Sample Code Link 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/hwr7po1m/3/ - With angular 1.6.10

Selected item is not displaying in the dropdown

Should show the selected item

Comment: Using Angular 1.0.7 is working, but same behaviour is not available with angular 1.6.10

Comment: Hi, it works for me (I'm using Chrome).

Comment: @WilliamHampshire Can you share a snippet or tell me why in 1st code link(Jsfiddle) is not working.

Comment: Yea you have selectedItem = ["C"] it should be the string "C" not the array of one string...

Comment: How come http://jsfiddle.net/hwr7po1m/3/ this link is working @william i am confused so

Comment: Without converting to string it's still works so

Comment: I just gave a further explanation. Comment on my answer if you need any further help on why it has to be a string for the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Selected item value should be a string instead of array

just change

```
$scope.selectedItemvalue = ["C"];
```

to

```
$scope.selectedItemvalue = "C";
```

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0t8meEjByliRpcbfJBBh?p=preview)

Comment: I don't want it to convert in string.

Comment: any specific reason or you are taking a test of devs here?

Comment: may be some new feature implemented in latest version

Comment: So then no other workaround in the latest version of angular right except converting to string ..

Comment: i will not recommend this but you can remove `ng-selected` directive and change `ng-model` to `ng-model="selectedItem[0]"` also works https://plnkr.co/edit/KjYtNj0c6KiiS8dijlpw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the `selectedItem` initially to an *array* of one string (["item"] in the first example and ["C"] in the second example) instead of setting it to the *value* of the selected item.

It works in the Angular 1.6.10 because in that version of angular "C" == ["C"] evaluates to TRUE.

In Angular 1.0.7 "C" == ["C"] evaluates to FALSE.

**So to fix your issue, you should set your selected item to be the string "C".**

JS:

```
$scope.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
$scope.selectedItem = "item1";
```

HTML:

```
<div class="field">
      <select id="" class="ui fluid search dropdown" ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option value=" ">Select Value</option>
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-selected="item == selectedItem" ng-value="item">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

UPDATE: It seems like the confusion is you're asking *why* I am "converting" the selected item to a string. I'm not converting anything actually. The original list is an ARRAY of STRINGS, so each individual item in the array is a string. Therefore by having the selected item be of type string, I'm only calling the item in the list what it actually is.